# How to add files to a non-executable or non-library target with CMake

Tags: cmake

I understand I can add some files to a target in CMake if the target is an executable or a library with the following command:

```
add_executable(${target_name} ${source_files})
```

or `add_library(${target_name} ${source_files})`

Then my question is what if the target is not an an executable or a library. I raise this question because I want to build a target for documentation with Doxygen, and this can be done with the following commands:

```
find_package(Doxygen)
if(DOXYGEN_FOUND)
  set(doxyfile_in  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Doxyfile.in) #doxygen file
  set(doxyfile    ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile)
  #configure the doxygen file
  configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Doxygen.in ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile @ONLY)
  add_custom_target( doc ALL
    COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${doxyfile}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}
    COMMENT "Generating API documentation with Doxygen" VERBATIM
  )
endif(DOXYGEN_FOUND)
```

With Visual Studio, `doc` becomes a target, and I also want to add `Doxyfile.in` file in the project just in case that I need to change some variables inside with the IDE. Any ideas on how I can add this file on the `doc` target? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `SOURCES` argument of [`add_custom_target`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3aadd_custom_target) for this:

```
add_custom_target( doc ALL
  COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${doxyfile}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}
  COMMENT "Generating API documentation with Doxygen" VERBATIM
  SOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Doxygen.in
)
```