# put source files in INSTALL target with cmake

Tags: cmake

I asked a question [How to add files to a non-executable or non-library target with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21914020/how-to-add-files-to-a-non-executable-or-non-library-target-with-cmake) a few days ago, and the best solution to this problem is to use `add_custom_target` command.

However, this solution may not work if the target is created by CMAKE itself. For example, the INSTALL target that is created automatically when running CMAKE. Suppose, I also put some additional files under the INSTALL project, what should I do? I have tried the following command, but failed:

```
add_custom_target( INSTALL  
  SOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/file_to_be_added.h
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake's default `INSTALL` target cannot be modified. You can however add a custom target, which does the same thing as the `INSTALL` target and has additional files added, e.g.:

```
add_custom_target(myinstall
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" "-DBUILD_TYPE=$<CONFIGURATION>"
        "-P" "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_install.cmake"
    SOURCES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/file_to_be_added.h"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
```